# Create Setup project for MVC4 Application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, setup-project

I have MVC4 web application and I need to make an exe installer to deploy the application and the DB on the customer's server

also application should be available online

Update: I have completed web application now i have to start for `setup` project

Comment: SO is not a place to keep personal notes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Publishing online will depend on the host - what they support but a good place to start would be to see if you can use the publishing wizard - right click on the web project and select publish. This requires some configuration but will work for Azure for example.

The msi/exe creation is altogether a more complex problem there are a number of options including installshield - I believe there is an installshield (light) setup project in visual studio. If you need something more advanced then there is the option of the paid for installshield but there is also the wix toolset http://wixtoolset.org which enables you to build msbuild installation packages. The learning curve is steep and the last time I used wix you weren't able to build a web installer out of the box - there were configuration options and additional tasks require before it would do this. That said it is possible to use Wix to build a very slick and quite powerful installer.